# reading multiple tabs from excel in different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read multiple tabs in spreadsheet to different dataframes and once all tabs with data are over the program should stop.

For first part I am looking to do something like

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('Unique.xlsx') 
for i in range(1,n): # n should be number of tabs with data
 try:
    df_Sector(i)=xls.parse('Sheet'+i) # df_Sector(i) has to be dataframe
 except:
    pass
```

I want the program to stop once all tabs with data are read

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Demo:

file name

```
In [94]: fn = r'D:\temp\.data\test.xlsx'
```

creating `pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile` object

```
In [95]: xl = pd.ExcelFile(fn)
```

it has `sheet_names` attribute

```
In [96]: xl.sheet_names
Out[96]: ['Sheet1', 'aaa']
```

we can use it for looping through sheets

```
In [98]: for sh in xl.sheet_names:
    ...:     df = xl.parse(sh)
    ...:     print('Processing: [{}] ...'.format(sh))
    ...:     print(df.head())
    ...:
Processing: [Sheet1] ...
   col1  col2  col3
0    11    12    13
1    21    22    23
2    31    32    33
Processing: [aaa] ...
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

a bit more elegant way is to generate a dictionary of DataFrames:

```
In [100]: dfs = {sh:xl.parse(sh) for sh in xl.sheet_names}

In [101]: dfs.keys()
Out[101]: dict_keys(['Sheet1', 'aaa'])

In [102]: dfs['Sheet1']
Out[102]:
   col1  col2  col3
0    11    12    13
1    21    22    23
2    31    32    33

In [103]: dfs['aaa']
Out[103]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

Comment: @user2560244, glad i could help

Comment: Amazing, but to access each df, I need to call via dfs['<name>']. Is there any possibility to create several data frames, such as df_name_of_the_sheet1, df_name_of_the_sheet2, etc? thanks!

Comment: @Luis, no, AFAIK you can't do this. But i think it's even more flexible to have it stored in the dictionary, so you can access it this way: `dfs["Sheet1"]`, `dfs["Sheet2"]`, etc. You can work with this dict programmatically using loops... And you can always do: `df_sheet1 = dfs["Sheet1"]` if you want ;)

Comment: Cool. Thank you!

Comment: `pandas` support `sheet_name=None` to read all sheet, and that is faster. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71977891/11671779) for benchmark.

Answer (score 3):

This will read all sheets and make a dictionary of dataframes:

```
xl = pd.read_excel('Unique.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

To get specific sheets, you could do:

```
xl_dict = {}
sheetname_list = ['blah1', 'blah2', 'blah3']
for sheet in sheetname_list:
    xl_dict[sheet] = pd.read_excel('Unique.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet)
```

or:

```
xl = pd.read_excel('Unique.xlsx', sheet_name=sheetname_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, however, here we are passing down "sheetname_list" under the assumption that we know how many sheets are there. In case, I do not know how many sheets(or tabs) are there with data and like to stop after all data in different tabs has been stored in different dataframes, what logic should i follow in that case.

Comment: The first code line in my answer will read all of the sheets which exist in the workbook and place them into a dictionary as dataframes.  The "sheetname_list" option is for when you know the names of the target sheets, as you mention.  Try the line with "sheetname=None" and see if that might do what you are requesting.  You can get the names of the worksheets stored as dictionary keys with xl.keys() after reading the excel file, and access the dataframes with xl[<worksheet name>].

Answer (score 2):

**USE `sheet_name=None` TO PARSE ALL SHEET!**

Approach answered by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42887787/11671779) is faster compared to make `ExcelFile` first.

Benchmark:

```py
%%timeit
dfs = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=None)
# 279 ms ± 20.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
xl = pd.ExcelFile(path)
dfs = {sh:xl.parse(sh) for sh in xl.sheet_names}
# 335 ms ± 40.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```